# cqlsh 'Select' statement does not return the data that exists

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, datastax-enterprise

I have the following Cassandra table:

```
CREATE TABLE myflights.flights_by_airport2 (
origin text,
dep_time timestamp,
fl_date timestamp,
airline_id int,
carrier text,
fl_num int,
PRIMARY KEY ((origin), dep_time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (dep_time ASC);


cqlsh:myflights> select * from flights_by_airport2 limit 5;

 origin | dep_time                        | airline_id | carrier | fl_date                         | fl_num
--------+---------------------------------+------------+---------+---------------------------------+--------
    MSY | 2012-01-01 05:57:00.000000+0000 |      19977 |      UA | 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000000+0000 |    275
    MSY | 2012-01-01 06:01:00.000000+0000 |      20409 |      B6 | 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000000+0000 |    110
    MSY | 2012-01-01 06:13:00.000000+0000 |      19790 |      DL | 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000000+0000 |    551
    MSY | 2012-01-01 06:45:00.000000+0000 |      19805 |      AA | 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000000+0000 |   1190
    MSY | 2012-01-01 06:46:00.000000+0000 |      19977 |      UA | 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000000+0000 |   1184
```

The following statement returns no data:

```
cqlsh:myflights>  select * from flights_by_airport2 where origin = 'MSY';

 origin | dep_time | airline_id | carrier | fl_date | fl_num
--------+----------+------------+---------+---------+--------

(0 rows)
```

I have a single-node Cassandra and Spark (DSE 6 cluster) installed on a Ubuntu VM.

Comment: I would first check if it is a whitespace issue by running `where origin contains 'MSY'`

Comment: I removed all leading spaces from the source file and refreshed Cassandra tables. It works now. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my comment has resulted in the answer I'm going to post it as the answer:

I would first check if it is a whitespace issue by running

```
select * from flights_by_airport2 where origin contains 'MSY';
```

If that remains an issue then you could try using `trim`, or just clean the data.

Comment: I am unable to vote up as I do not have enough credits. I wish I could. Thank you so much for helping me.